# TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() returns null on Huawei P Smart

Tags: android, telephony

The code works perfect on Samsung and Sony devices but on Huawei P Smart getAllCellInfo() returns null. 
Some snippets:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            List<CellInfo> cellInfo = ((TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getAllCellInfo();
        }
    }
```

The app has ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission. Geolocation services are turned on.